# Datomic hides parts of its history when query is about all attributes

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have a datomic query:

```
(pprint (d/q '[:find ?tx ?attr ?val ?op :in $ ?e :where [?e ?attr ?val ?tx ?op]] (d/history (d/db db/conn)) 17592186766274))
```

that yields:

```
#{[13194140264981 354 6 true] 
  [13194140265425 352 "OK" true] 
  [13194140255168 348 17592186593957 true] 
  [13194140265425 353 true true] 
  [13194140255168 311 #uuid "6086bec6-7a11-4238-9ce3-67e6427d7b07" true] 
  [13194140255168 346 17592186491729 true] 
  [13194140265424 351 #uuid "60871d86-cdc2-4ddf-b091-98117c3948af" true] 
  [13194140265425 349 #inst "2021-04-26T20:29:34.566-00:00" true] 
  [13194140255168 347 "{:driver \"6144c7bd-8e71-49c3-8eef-2e9d157f3e11\", :order \"c89d32d2-92da-4cde-827d-da6406877c28\"}\n" true] 
  [13194140265424 350 #inst "2021-04-26T20:29:34.472-00:00" true] 
  [13194140255168 356 #inst "2021-04-26T18:23:18.140-00:00" true]}
```

Please note that attribute 354 is shown to be changed in history once only (to value 6).
Then, if we ask for this particular attribute...

```
(pprint (d/q '[:find ?tx ?val ?op :in $ ?e :where [?e 354 ?val ?tx ?op]] (d/history (d/db db/conn)) 17592186766274))
```

... we suddenly find that it has been modified multiple times:

```
#{[13194140264479 1 false] 
  [13194140264516 2 false] 
  [13194140264585 4 true] 
  [13194140264981 6 true] 
  [13194140264721 4 false] 
  [13194140264461 1 true] 
  [13194140264479 2 true] 
  [13194140264721 5 true] 
  [13194140264516 3 true] 
  [13194140264585 3 false] 
  [13194140264981 5 false]}
```

Furthermore, if we ask the original question agains the current database instead of history, we get the same result!

```
(pprint (d/q '[:find ?tx ?attr ?val ?op :in $ ?e :where [?e ?attr ?val ?tx ?op]] (d/db db/conn) 17592186766274))
```

gives:

```
#{[13194140264981 354 6 true] 
  [13194140265425 352 "OK" true] 
  [13194140255168 348 17592186593957 true] 
  [13194140265425 353 true true] 
  [13194140255168 311 #uuid "6086bec6-7a11-4238-9ce3-67e6427d7b07" true] 
  [13194140255168 346 17592186491729 true] 
  [13194140265424 351 #uuid "60871d86-cdc2-4ddf-b091-98117c3948af" true] 
  [13194140265425 349 #inst "2021-04-26T20:29:34.566-00:00" true] 
  [13194140255168 347 "{:driver \"6144c7bd-8e71-49c3-8eef-2e9d157f3e11\", :order \"c89d32d2-92da-4cde-827d-da6406877c28\"}\n" true] 
  [13194140265424 350 #inst "2021-04-26T20:29:34.472-00:00" true] 
  [13194140255168 356 #inst "2021-04-26T18:23:18.140-00:00" true]}
```

It looks as if the question for all attribute changes for an entity was too general, but no error is returned and wrong answer is presented. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know what has happened. All the attributes for this entity had :db/noHistory set to true. It is still quite mysterious why the changes still show when we query for a particular attribute.

Comment: While setting `:db/noHistory` should lessen the overall amount stored in history there are no guarantees about how much history is kept and some amount of history may be visible even for attributes with `:db/noHistory` set to true.